# Set variable in parent scope in Twig

Tags: templates, variables, scope, twig, variable-assignment

In Smarty you can do

```
{$var = 'bla' scope=parent}
```

Is it possible in Twig?

Don't suggest to use blocks. I know. I need variable.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: @Cyrus, long time has passed. I'm not currently into twig or php. I guess I just choose the most elaborated answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to use the `default()` filter (i.e., when you want to use the variable multiple times throughout your parent and child templates), you can actually define a block that contains your entire page in the parent template, and then nest your other blocks inside of that:

```
{# base.twig #}

{# Default page properties.  You can override these in the `page` block of your child templates. #}
{% set page = page | default({}) | merge({
    "title"       : "My Default Title",
    "description" : "Default description"
}) %}

{% block page %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta name="description" content="{{ page.description }}"> 
            <title>{{ page.title }}</title>

            ...

        </head>
        <body>
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </body>
    </html>
{% endblock %}
```

You can then override the `page` variable in the `page` block in your child template, by setting the value **and then** calling `parent()`:

```
{# child.twig #}

{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block page %}
    {# By putting this in a special block, we ensure that it will be set AFTER the default values are set in the parent template, 
    but BEFORE the page itself is rendered. #}

    {% set page = page | merge({
        "title"       : "Child Page",
        "description" : "Welcome to the child page!"
    }) %}    

    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

Note that in the parent template, we define the `page` variable outside of the `page` block, while in the child template we define it **inside** the `page` block.

So, Twig will do the following:

1. When it renders `child.twig`, it will start from the top of `base.twig`, setting the default values for the `page` variable.
2. When it comes to the `page` **block**, it will see that `child.twig` overrides that block.  So, it will run the `page` block in `child.twig` instead.
3. Inside the `page` block in `child.twig`, it will set the new values for the `page` variable.  It will then call `parent()`, which tells it to go back to `base.twig` and render the parent `page` block.
4. It will then continue to render the page, substituting any additional blocks as defined in `child.twig` (in my example, it will render the `content` block).

See a working example [here](http://twigfiddle.com/0x0exu).  Do be aware that this can become more complicated when you start adding multiple layers of inheritance (e.g., grandchild templates).

Comment: Thanks. `{% set page = page | default({}) | merge({` seems to be exactly what I needed to learn.

Answer (score 14):

base.twig

```
<title>{{ title|default('example.com') }} - My cool site</title>
```

child.twig

```
{% set title = 'ChildTitle' %}
```

Comment: I believe this only works if `set title` is set before the `<title>` tag is output as you have above. Is there a solution where the `title` variable is set _after_ the `<title>` tag in the template?

Answer (score 8):

If you simply want a variable to be 'overridable' from a subtemplate you can set your variable in the parent like so:

```
{% set title = (title|default('My Page')) %}
```

So you could set up a situation like this...

base.twig

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% end block %}
  </body>
</html>
```

parent.twig

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}

{% set title = (title|default('My Page')) %}
```

child.twig

```
{% extends 'parent.twig' %} 

{% set title='My Subpage' %}   

{% block content %}
  This is the Sub-page.
{% end block %}
```

The end result will be:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Subpage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is the Sub-page.
  </body>
</html>
```

I think that works nicely for most situations. Rather than forcing the parent var to be overridden by the child, the parent 'lets' the variable be overridden by children. You could also define different behaviour in the parent such as concatenation rather than overriding.

Answer (score 7):

@n3xus gave a nice answer, it actually helped me also (thanks), but you may also want to take a look at this page from the documentation: [Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html)

One particularly nice feature is the ability to set a chunk of text/html:

```
{% set title %}
    <i class="icon-user"></i>
    {{ user.username | capitalize }}
    <small>{{ user.email | lower }}</small>
{% endset %}
```

Makes it easy to generate very specific bits of content from the child templates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following in your child pages:

```
{% set title = 'your desired title' %}
```

Answer (score 2):

A great way to do something like this i just discovered:

parent.twig

```
{% set subvar = block('subvar') %}

{# somewhere later #}

{{ subvar }}
```

child.twig

```
{% block subvar %}
    anything you want
{% endblock %}
```

if your child template does not define the block `subvar`, the variable in `parent.twig` will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

One other approach is to see twig configuration globally in your application. For example in Silex:

```
$app['twig']->addGlobal('someuser', $user);
```

You can then access that variable in all templates:

```
Hello, {{someuser.name}}
```

Comment: Ok, how about doing the same inside template?

Answer (score -1):

Use [**set**  tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html) with [embed](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html)

Example:

***parent.twig***:

```
{%  block child %}

{% endblock %}

I say: {{ var }}
```

***child.twig***:

```
 {% embed "parent.twig" %}
     {% block child %}
 I child, but i not to fail set    
         {% endblock %}
    {%  set var='bla' %}

 {% endembed %}
```

Comment: this won't affect parent scope

Comment: Yes if you use extend but use [embed](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html). See my update

Comment: Could you please post a new answer with clear usage exmple without bad variant and wierd 'NonluxCiBundle:...', or update this one, so I can accept it?