# Twig setting variable in parent template

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

I have several templates in which I need to write the literals for the day of the week and month. I created a small twig file:

```
{% set numDay = target.dateStop | date ("w", user_timezone) %}
{% set daysOfWeek = {0: 'Sunday', 1: 'Monday', 2: 'Tuesday', 3: 'Wednesday', 4: 'Thursday', 5: 'Friday', 6: 'Saturday'} %}
{% set weekDay = daysOfWeek[numDay] %}

{% set numMonth = target.dateStop | date ("n", user_timezone) %}
{% set months = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'} %}
{% set month = months[numMonth] %
```

In the template where I need these values I first include the "helper" template

```
{% include '@.../Email/HTML/en_US/localized_day_and_month.twig' with [user_timezone] %}
```

Then simply use the variable

```
... {{ weekDay }} ...
```

I still get this error:

> failed: Variable "weekDay" does not exist in ".../HTML/it_IT:do_deadline_new.html.twig" at line 9

I know there's probably a better solution to my "localized date problem" but that's not my point here

**EDIT**

I moved the first snippet inside the base class I inherit in every template, but those variables still seem to be ignored:

*base.html.twig*

```
{% block dateTimeVariables %}
    {% set numDay = target.dateStop | date ("w", user_timezone) %}
    {% set daysOfWeek = {0: 'Domenica', 1: 'Lunedì', 2: 'Martedì', 3: 'Mercoledì', 4: 'Giovedì', 5: 'Venerdì', 6: 'Sabato'} %}
    {% set weekDay = daysOfWeek[numDay] %}

    {% set numMonth = target.dateStop | date ("n", user_timezone) %}
    {% set months = {1: 'gennaio', 2: 'febbraio', 3: 'marzo', 4: 'aprile', 5: 'maggio', 6: 'giugno', 7: 'luglio', 8: 'agosto', 9: 'settembre', 10: 'ottobre', 11: 'novembre', 12: 'dicembre'} %}
    {% set month = months[numMonth] %}
{% endblock %}
```

And in the child template:

```
{% extends '@.../Email/HTML/it_IT/base.html.twig' %}
```

And yet:

> failed: Variable "weekDay" does not exist in ".../HTML/it_IT:do_deadline_new.html.twig" at line 6

The line 6 is this:

```
[{{ group.name }}] Today at {{ target.created | date("H:i", user_timezone) }} {{ agent.name }} {{ agent.surname }} has created a file due on {{ weekDay | lower }} {{ target.dateStop | date ("d", user_timezone) }} {{ month }} at {{ target.dateStop | date ("H:i", user_timezone) }}.
```

Comment: which version of twig are you using ?

Comment: @gioaudino your problem might be solved similarly to the solution I outline in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32642249/2970321

Answer (score 0):

From [twig doc :](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html)

> The include statement includes a template and returns the rendered content of that file into the current namespace.

AFAIK the included file will only be rendered , any variable that had been set in the included file will not be added to the parent namespace.

So try to use extends instead. Something like this :

**parent.twig**

```
   {% set numDay = target.dateStop | date ("w", user_timezone) %}
   {% set daysOfWeek = {0: 'Sunday', 1: 'Monday', 2: 'Tuesday', 3: 'Wednesday', 4: 'Thursday', 5: 'Friday', 6: 'Saturday'} %}
   {% set weekDay = daysOfWeek[numDay] %}

   {% set numMonth = target.dateStop | date ("n", user_timezone) %}
   {% set months = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'} %}
   {% set month = months[numMonth] %}
```

**child.twig**

```
{% extends 'parent.twig'%}
```

Comment: Actually the template where I include the localized_day_and_month is already extending another template and multiple inheritance is not allowed. I guess the best choice is to move those variable setters into the parent template and only extend that one removing the include statements

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Comment: I still get that error. I edited the question to show the changes

Comment: ok i think i know the probleme. remove `{% block dateTimeVariables %}` , just set the variables directly in base template.